# Exponential equations solving methods?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, exponential-function

Do you have an idea or general method to solve the following equation?:
$$a^{\alpha x}+b^{\beta x} = c^{\gamma x}+ d^{\delta x}$$
when $a,b,c,d$ aren't zero, and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are real numbers.
The cause of this question was a particular problem found in this site. 
Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: In the general case, there is no analytical method, i.e. the result is not expressed with a formula. One currently use some numerical methods, i.e. the result is expressed with number(s). In some cases, it is possible to find formulas giving aproximate results on limited range of parameters.

Comment: The trouble is that there is no general rule for simplifying $ \ B^{\alpha} \ + \ B^{\beta} \ . $ So while one could put all of the exponential terms into a common base (for instance, $ \ a^{\alpha x} \ = \ e^{(\ln a \ \cdot \ \alpha) \ x} , $ and so forth), there isn't much one could do in general with the equation after that...